# Android ICS using HttpURLConnection with https address can't do post methods

Tags: android, post, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, httpurlconnection

I'm using this code since API lvl 4 and it always worked, until ICS.
Since API level 14 when I use a https URL this block of code always performs a GET method and not a POST. If I use an http URL the code performs a POST and it all works.
The exception I'm getting since lvl14 is FileNotFoundException. I'm not understanding at all what is happening. Please help. Thank you.

```
private byte[] Post(byte[] Header, byte[] Body, String protocol) throws IOException, MyAppConnectionException
{
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    byte[] responseData = null;

    try
    {
        String url = MyApp.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.ServerEndPoint);
        URL u = new URL(url);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(45000);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("CONTENT-TYPE", protocol);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true); 
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
        urlConnection.connect();
    }
    catch(IOException ioex)
    {
        throw new MyAppConnectionException();
    }

    if(urlConnection != null)
    {
        DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());

        int msgLength = (int)(4 + Header.length + Body.length);

        outputStream.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putInt(msgLength).array());
        outputStream.write(Header);
        outputStream.write(Body);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        if(urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

            int dataLength = inputStream.available();
            byte[] msgbLength = new byte[4];
            inputStream.read(msgbLength, 0, 4);
            int length = ByteBuffer.wrap(msgbLength).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt();

            assert(dataLength == length);      

            responseData = new byte[length - 4];
            inputStream.readFully(responseData, 0, length - 4);
            inputStream.close();
        }
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }

    return responseData;}
```

Comment: there was a change where regarding POST and GET but afaik it was that if you do `urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);` it will always perform a POST where it previously was a GET

Comment: the thing is that it actually does a POST if I use a http URL, if its https setdooutput(true) does nothing and the method is GET...

Comment: if you add `urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");`?

Comment: tried that, tried initializing a HttpsURLConnection object instead of HttpURLConnection, it always does GET method.

Comment: Try `Content-Type` instead of `CONTENT-TYPE`.

Comment: Already tried but still no success. It all works if I use a http URL, but with https, if I inspect the content of urlConnection the property method has the value GET and doOutput has the value false.

Comment: It seems its not possible anymore to do POST requests to https URLs using HttpURLConnection. Re-implemented with HttpPost, HttpClient and HttpResponse. It works in all versions of Android. Thank you all.

Comment: Actually, I thought I had a problem with HttpURLConnection doing a GET instead of POST. A GET would give me a 404 from the server and I got a FileNotFoundException back. Also when I debugged the HttpURLConnection it looked like the implementaiton of HttpURLConnection on ICS didn't change the method from GET to POST when setting request method and that it should output data. However, when I looked in the server log I saw that I got a 400 back and that HttpURLConnection throws FileNotFoundException for all 4XX status codes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing `urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setRequestMethod(java.lang.String)